# How to define a neural network that maps real-valued 2D matrix to binary 2D matrix?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, loss-functions

I'm doing some tests with matrix to matrix neural networks.

In my setting, I'm trying to develop a neural network that can map a real-valued matrix to a binary matrix. The input matrix is a random distribution of real numbers. The output matrix indicates, for each line, which is the smallest value of the input matrix. That is, if in the input matrix, the column j has the smallest value for the line x, the cell in of the output matrix would have the value 1, and for all other columns, the line x would have the value 0.

Bellow I will provide an example of a 3X3 input and output matrix.
Input:

[[0.5,0.6,0.2],
[0.1,0.5,0.9],
[0.5,0.4,0.6]]

Output:

[[0,0,1],
[1,0,0],
[0,1,0]]

This is a trivial problem that can be easily solved by a simple and straightforward algorithm. But I'm interested in trying to solve this by neural networks, for gaining insights about how to work with 2D matrices as inputs and outputs.

I've developed a scrip (bellow) for generating random datasets and for building and training a neural network. But the achieved accuracy is very low. I think that I'm using the wrong activation function for the last layer of the network, and the wrong loss function for the training. Which would be the best choices for activation and loss functions in this context?

Notice that I'm interested in taking a 2D matrix as the input of my neural network model and having as output a 2D matrix. The idea is not to deal with rows separately. I would like to do something similar to what is done in image-to-image neural networks, but with matrices that are representing non-visual information.

My script:

````py
import os
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import random
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def randomMatrix(matrixSize,maxValue):
    matrix = []
    for i in range(matrixSize):
        line = []
        for j in range(matrixSize):
            value = (random.random()*maxValue)
            line.append(value)
        matrix.append(line)
    return np.array(matrix)
    
def generatesOutputFromInput(matrix):
    output = []
    rows, cols = matrix.shape
    for i in range(rows):
        line = []
        minVal = matrix[i,0]
        for j in range(cols):
            value = matrix[i,j]
            if value < minVal:
                minVal = value
        for j in range(cols):
            value = matrix[i,j]
            if value == minVal:
                line.append(1)
            else:
                line.append(0)
        output.append(line)
    return np.array(output)

def builtDataset(datasetSize,matrixSize,maxValue):
    inputs = []
    outputs = []
    for i in range(datasetSize):
        inputM = randomMatrix(matrixSize,maxValue)
        outputM = generatesOutputFromInput(inputM)
        inputs.append(inputM)
        outputs.append(outputM)
    return np.array(inputs),np.array(outputs)
    
matrixSize = 5
maxValue = 200
epochs = 20
datasetSize = 200000

inputs,outputs = builtDataset(datasetSize,matrixSize,maxValue)
print("inputs ",len(inputs))
print("outputs ",len(outputs))

print(inputs[0])
print(outputs[0])

seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(inputs, outputs, test_size=0.1, random_state=seed)

es = EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', mode='min', verbose=1,min_delta=0.01, patience=20)
lr_schedule = keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(initial_learning_rate=0.001, decay_steps=1600, decay_rate=0.95)
rmsprop = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=lr_schedule, momentum=0.3)

model = keras.models.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Dense((matrixSize*matrixSize)/2, input_shape=(matrixSize,matrixSize), activation="relu"),   
        keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        keras.layers.Flatten(),
        keras.layers.Dense((matrixSize*matrixSize)/4, activation="relu"),
        keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        keras.layers.Dense((matrixSize*matrixSize)/2, activation="relu"), 
        keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        keras.layers.Dense(matrixSize*matrixSize, activation="sigmoid"),
        keras.layers.Reshape((matrixSize, matrixSize))
])

model.compile(optimizer=rmsprop,loss="mean_squared_error", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.summary()

history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=100, callbacks=[es], shuffle=True, epochs=epochs, validation_split=0.1)

score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)
print("Test loss:", score[0])
print("Test accuracy:", score[1])

plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```
````

Comment: What's a 2D matrix? How is it different from an ordinary matrix? Since there's only 1 smallest value in each row, why are you using a sigmoid activation instead of softmax?

Comment: @Sycorax , a 2D matrix is a matrix with two dimensions, as the ones in the examples. I'm not using softmax because I'm generating the whole matrix in the output and it has one 1 per line. I think that softmax is not suitable for this context. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Ok, so why not reshape it to be amenable to softmax?

Comment: @Sycorax, in my point of view, the shape is not the main problem here. The problem is that I will have an output (let's say, a unidimensional vector reshaped) with a lot of 1's. If my matrix is 3X3, as in the example, I will have 3 values equal to 1. In the general, softmax outputs a probability distribution. It seems that this is not the case here.

Comment: Which point in my question is not clear? Please, I would like to understand, in an explicit way, what you haven't understood.

Comment: The dimension of a matrix is given by two numbers, which is usually denoted as $m \times n$ for a matrix with $m$ rows and $n$ columns. This should **not** be confused with the notion of a 2D array, which is an abstract data type whose entries can be specified with two indices. 2D arrays can be used to represent matrices, which has led to confusion for those that have not sufficiently studied one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

I think that I have developed a good model for the task.
I've used sigmoid function as the activation function of the last layer and mse loss function. Besides that, I've used a simplified version of my original proposed architecture and used more data.

In some runs I've obtained more than 90% of accuracy.

[image: Model accuracy]

[image: Model loss]

This is my script:

```
import os
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import random
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def randomMatrix(matrixSize,maxValue):
    matrix = []
    for i in range(matrixSize):
        line = []
        for j in range(matrixSize):
            value = (random.random()*maxValue)
            line.append(value)
        matrix.append(line)
    return np.array(matrix)
    
def generatesOutputFromInput(matrix):
    output = []
    rows, cols = matrix.shape
    for i in range(rows):
        line = []
        minVal = matrix[i,0]
        for j in range(cols):
            value = matrix[i,j]
            if value < minVal:
                minVal = value
        for j in range(cols):
            value = matrix[i,j]
            if value == minVal:
                line.append(1)
            else:
                line.append(0)
        output.append(line)
    return np.array(output)

def builtDataset(datasetSize,matrixSize,maxValue):
    inputs = []
    outputs = []
    for i in range(datasetSize):
        inputM = randomMatrix(matrixSize,maxValue)
        outputM = generatesOutputFromInput(inputM)
        inputs.append(inputM)
        outputs.append(outputM)
    return np.array(inputs),np.array(outputs)
    
matrixSize = 5
maxValue = 200
epochs = 20
datasetSize = 300000

inputs,outputs = builtDataset(datasetSize,matrixSize,maxValue)
print("inputs ",len(inputs))
print("outputs ",len(outputs))

print(inputs[0])
print(outputs[0])

seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(inputs, outputs, test_size=0.1, random_state=seed)

es = EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', mode='min', verbose=1,min_delta=0.01, patience=20)
lr_schedule = keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(initial_learning_rate=0.001, decay_steps=1600, decay_rate=0.95)
rmsprop = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=lr_schedule, momentum=0.3)

model = keras.models.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Dense(100, input_shape=(matrixSize,matrixSize), activation="relu"),   
        keras.layers.Flatten(),
        keras.layers.Dense(30, activation="relu"),
        keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="relu"), 
        keras.layers.Dense(matrixSize*matrixSize, activation="sigmoid"),
        keras.layers.Reshape((matrixSize, matrixSize))
])

model.compile(optimizer=rmsprop,loss="mse", metrics=["accuracy"])

model.summary()

history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=100, callbacks=[es], shuffle=True, epochs=epochs, validation_split=0.1)

score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)
print("Test loss:", score[0])
print("Test accuracy:", score[1])

print(X_test[0])
print(Y_test[0])
prediction = model.predict(X_test)
print(prediction[0])

plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I've developed an even better model using a 2D convolutional layer. This model achieves around 99% of accuracy in the test dataset.

```
import os
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import random
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def randomMatrix(matrixSize,maxValue):
    matrix = []
    for i in range(matrixSize):
        line = []
        for j in range(matrixSize):
            value = (random.random()*maxValue)
            line.append(value)
        matrix.append(line)
    return np.array(matrix)
    
def generatesOutputFromInput(matrix):
    output = []
    rows, cols = matrix.shape
    for i in range(rows):
        line = []
        minVal = matrix[i,0]
        for j in range(cols):
            value = matrix[i,j]
            if value < minVal:
                minVal = value
        for j in range(cols):
            value = matrix[i,j]
            if value == minVal:
                line.append(1)
            else:
                line.append(0)
        output.append(line)
    return np.array(output)

def builtDataset(datasetSize,matrixSize,maxValue):
    inputs = []
    outputs = []
    for i in range(datasetSize):
        inputM = randomMatrix(matrixSize,maxValue)
        outputM = generatesOutputFromInput(inputM)
        inputs.append(inputM)
        outputs.append(outputM)
    return np.array(inputs),np.array(outputs)
    
matrixSize = 4
maxValue = 200
epochs = 60
datasetSize = 400000

inputs,outputs = builtDataset(datasetSize,matrixSize,maxValue)
print("inputs ",len(inputs))
print("outputs ",len(outputs))

print(inputs[0])
print(outputs[0])

seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(inputs, outputs, test_size=0.1, random_state=seed)

es = EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', mode='min', verbose=1,min_delta=0.01, patience=20)
lr_schedule = keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(initial_learning_rate=0.001, decay_steps=1600, decay_rate=0.95)
rmsprop = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=lr_schedule, momentum=0.3)

model = keras.models.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Input(shape=(matrixSize,matrixSize)),
        keras.layers.Reshape((-1, matrixSize, matrixSize, 1)),
        keras.layers.Conv2D(matrixSize, kernel_size=(2, 2), activation="relu"),
        keras.layers.Dense(100, input_shape=(matrixSize,matrixSize), activation="relu"),   
        keras.layers.Flatten(),
        keras.layers.Dense(30, activation="relu"),
        keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="relu"), 
        keras.layers.Dense(matrixSize*matrixSize, activation="sigmoid"),
        keras.layers.Reshape((matrixSize, matrixSize))
])

model.compile(optimizer=rmsprop,loss="mse", metrics=["accuracy"])

model.summary()

history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=100, callbacks=[es], shuffle=True, epochs=epochs, validation_split=0.1)

score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)
print("Test loss:", score[0])
print("Test accuracy:", score[1])

print(X_test[0])
print(Y_test[0])
prediction = model.predict(X_test)
print(prediction[0])

plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```